# logging mercurial transactions

Tags: mercurial, shell

this is a small addition to the previous script, and this time I would like to log details for the backup.

```
script /tmp/commit-push-log

# add all files to the repository
for REPOSITORY in $@ 
do

    cd $REPOSITORY

    # commit the changes
    hg commit -A -m "Commit changes `date`"

    # push the changes to the remote repository
    if hg push 
    then
        logger hg push completed without failure
    else
        logger hg push fails
    fi

done

exit

cat /tmp/commit-push-log | logger

rm /tmp/commit-push-log
```

the problem is that i don't see any mercurial messages in the log. What can go wrong in my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my current version

```
for REPOSITORY in $@ 
do

    # new temp file
    OUTPUT_LOG=`tempfile`
    echo -n > $OUTPUT_LOG

    # checks whether $REPO is a repo
    if [ ! -d $REPOSITORY/.hg ]; then
      echo "Not a repository: $REPOSITORY"
      exit 1;
    fi

    # change to that dir
    cd "$REPOSITORY"

    logger "Repository: $REPOSITORY"

    # commit the changes
    hg commit -A -m "Commit changes `date`" 2>&1 >> $OUTPUT_LOG

    # push the changes to the remote repository
    if hg push 2>&1 >> $OUTPUT_LOG
    then
    logger hg push completed without failure
    else
    logger hg push fails
    exit 1;
    fi

    # log the contents and delete the tempfile
    cat $OUTPUT_LOG | logger

    rm -f $OUTLOG_LOG

done

exit 0
```

Comment: You didn't quote $OUTPUT_LOG properly and 10th line $REPOSITORY/.hg is not quoted. Try `export TMPDIR="/tmp/space test"; mkdir "$TMPDIR` ; ./Your_script` # to see what I mean. +1 for `tempfile`, didn't know that one.

Answer (score 1):

1. You should not use static tmp filenames. Use mktemp, it's far safer.
2. You should `cd "$REPOSITORY"` instead of "cd $REPOSITORY" or things will get funny when REPOSITORY will contain any spaces or special characters.
3. You should not write automated commit comments. [See here](http://www.randsinrepose.com/archives/2006/03/23/capturing_context.html) for the great article on this topic.
4. **hg** probably outputs errors to stderr. Use `hg commit -A -m "$comment" 2>&1` and `hg push 2>&1`

Comment: the script mainly backups /var/log and /etc for monitoring purpose from external servers, so automated commit comments should be enough for the purpose